# answers order is not point-based?

Tags: bug, answers

I've been around SE for a while, but never seen answer with less points showing higher as here [A possible shorthand for equivalent focal length](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/283/a-possible-shorthand-for-equivalent-focal-length):[image: possible shorthand for equivalent focal length answer by mattdm]

Is that because mattdm is higher ranked or admin of meta@photo.SE? or is that a bug/feature otherwise?

Comment: For the record, mattdm is not an admin of this site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you have "active" clicked instead of "votes." @mattdm's answer is the most recent (written or edited) so it will appear at the top of the page when "active" is selected. For answers to be ranked by votes you need to select "votes."

[image]

Comment: thanks, that does make sense now. But I am pretty sure that's because default was "Active" on meta@photoSE